# How do I integrate jquery into an existing link menu to open pages in a defined div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm going to start this out by saying that this is my first attempt at creating a website since I was 12, which I can tell you was a NUMBER of years ago. At inception I utilized an iframe to display content, but ultimately decided that it had too many resizing limitations to be practical. So I created a DIV in my document named colTwo and managed to get my home.html to load into it when the page loads.

I have a pre-existing menu that is coded thusly:

```
    <!-- dd menu -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
    <!--
    var timeout         = 500;
    var closetimer    = 0;
    var ddmenuitem      = 0;

    // open hidden layer
    function mopen(id)
    {  
    // cancel close timer
    mcancelclosetime();

    // close old layer
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';

    // get new layer and show it
    ddmenuitem = document.getElementById(id);
    ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'visible';

    }
    // close showed layer
    function mclose()
    {
    if(ddmenuitem) ddmenuitem.style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }

    // go close timer
    function mclosetime()
    {
    closetimer = window.setTimeout(mclose, timeout);
    }

    // cancel close timer
    function mcancelclosetime()
    {
    if(closetimer)
    {
    window.clearTimeout(closetimer);
    closetimer = null;
    }
    }

    // close layer when click-out
    document.onclick = mclose; 
    // -->
    </script>
```

From what I have garnered from delving into the bowels of the Internet, I need to utilize jquery to have the links from the aforementioned navigation menu direct into the DIV. The one function I found was...

```
     $(function(){
     $('#menu li a').on('click', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var page_url=$(this).prop('href');
        $('#colTwo').load(page_url);
     });
     });
```

Once integrated properly, I should be able to add

```
     $('#colTwo').load(page_url + ' #colTwo');
```

to my HREF string and everything should work just swell.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to merge the function with the above javascript and despite trying many different ways, I'm at a loss. If there's another way to do it I'm all ears.

Any and all help/direction you can give me on this topic would be GREATLY appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation at:
http://api.jquery.com/load/

You should be able to use the following format:

```
$('#result').load('ajax/test.html #container');
```

Maybe try hardcoding the load into a new page to ensure it's working